# Ansible create user with password, dont change it if user exists

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, user-management

I have some servers which I want to administer with ansible. Currently I need to create user acounts on all of them. On some of them, some accounts are already present. I want to create the users with a default password, but if the user exist don't change his password.

Can someone help me with this condition ?

Here is my playbook :

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars:
    sudo_users:
       # password is generated through "mkpasswd" command from 'whois' package
      - login: user1
        password: hashed_password
      - login: user1
        password: hashed_password

  tasks:
    - name: Make sure we have a 'sudo' group
      group:
        name: sudo
        state: present

    - user:
        name: "{{ item.login }}"
        #password: "{{ item.password }}"
        shell: /bin/bash
        groups: "{{ item.login }},sudo"
        append: yes
      with_items: "{{ sudo_users }}"
```

Comment: This question should be closed, since its already documented on the Ansible docs site. Simple typo error...

Comment: I came here googling a problem in a similar context and found it helpful. If we closed all questions that were (a) typos or (b) documented elsewhere then SOF would be pretty deserted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/user_module.html) of user module:

> **update_password** (added in 1.3) `always`/`on_create`
>   `always` will update passwords if they differ. `on_create` will only set the password for newly created users.

Comment: Ha-ha, somehow I missed it :D Thanks